# CakePHP code error

Tags: cakephp

I have the following code which checks if the logged in user has calls to make and if so make background of the notification link on navigation bar red. I keep getting an error and I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. Can someone please help?

callsController:

```
class CallsController extends AppController {

//some code

public function index() {
        $userid=$this->Session->read('User.userid');
        if(isset($userid)&&$userid!=null)
        {
            $this->Call->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('calls', $this->Paginator->paginate());
            $result=$this->Employee->getcalls($userid);
            $this->set('result', $result);
        }
        else{
            $this->set('loggedout',"loggedout");
            $this->render("../Pages/home");
            $this->layout = '../Pages/home';
        }


    }

//some code
}
```

Call.php:

```
class Call extends AppModel {

//some code

public function getcalls($userid)
    {
        $this->setSource('calls');
        return $this->find('all',array('conditions' =>array('employees_id'=>$userid)
        ));
    }
}
```

calls/index.ctp:

```
<?php
$usertype=$this->SESSION->read('User.usertype');

if($usertype=="admin")
    echo $this->element('setTopNavigation');
else
    echo $this->element('setTopNavigationStaff');

//var_dump($calls);
$today=getdate();


//create todays date
$tyear=$today["year"];
$tmonth=$today["month"];
$tday=$today["mday"];
$datenow=date_create("$tyear-$tmonth-$tday");

$counter=0;

?>

<?php foreach ($result as $call):

    $calldate=$call['Employee']['next_call_date'];
    $calldate=date_create($calldate);
    $diff=date_diff($datenow,$calldate); //see the difference between two calls


    if($diff->format("%R%a")=="+0"){
        $counter++;

?>
    <?php } endforeach; ?>


<?php  if($counter!=0){?>
    <script>
       // $(".notification").css({"font-weight":"bold"});
        $(".notification").css({"background":"#edb4b4"});


    </script>

<?php }?>

<div class="callsIndex">
    <h2><?php echo __('Call Details'); ?>   </h2>
    <div class="bottomButtonnew"><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Calls'), array('action' => 'add')); ?></div>


    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['next_call_date']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Companies']['company_name'], array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'view', $call['Companies']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="actions">


                    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <p>
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
            'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total')
        ));
        ?>  </p>
    <div class="paging">
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
```

Comment: What error do you get and which line does it point to?

Comment: Call to a member function getcalls() on a non-object line 29 callsController @Juhana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace below line

```
$result=$this->Employee->getcalls($userid);
```

with

```
$result=$this->Call->getcalls($userid);
```

Comment: I tried changing to $result=$this->Call->getcalls($userid); and now I get the following error:
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'employees_id' in where clause is ambiguous @Bharat Maheshwari

Comment: use this return $this->find('all',array('conditions' =>array('Call.employees_id'=>$userid); in your model and try

Comment: It works, I don't get that error anymore but now the calls are loaded and the notification link background has changed to red but I get the following error:
Undefined index: Employee [APP\View\Calls\index.ctp, line 30] @Bharat Maheshwari

Comment: Actually i figured it out. Thanks for the help